# Is it possible to insert a .fig file into a website?

Tags: html, matlab, matlab-figure

I'm wondering if it is possible to insert a matlab .fig file into a website, making sure it remains interactive. I don't even know if this can be achieved, but if it can, I would love to know how. I tried just some simple code like such `<embed src="img/Astroph_Hull_Edge.fig">` and got the error

> " Refused to display 'https://website.com/img/Astroph_Hull_Edge.fig' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. "

Comment: You'd have to run MATLAB **on your website** in order to have a fully interactive .fig file with all capabilities it has in MATLAB's GUI. I doubt MATLAB would license that; you could check whether Octave offers the same level of interactiveness you want.

Comment: Thank you for this information :)

Comment: Possibly related to https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2008/02/18/interactive-web-pages-in-matlab-part-2, although it seems to allow Matlab to interact with web pages, which is not what @MaxGingold is looking for.

Comment: Almost all modern browser include a javascript engine, so you should choose an option that is javascript powered, such as [plotly](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plotly-graphs)

Comment: This would require a MATLAB [web app](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/compiler/web-apps.html), as such I've voted to close this question as off topic for being too broad, there is no reasonable, definitive, self-contained answer to this

Comment: @Wolfie how is it too broad? The problem of having an entity constructed from the IDE embedded in a distributable web page is super well-defined, and the Web App Compiler is built with more or less the direct intention of being a self-contained solution to the problem, allowing for the fact that the interactive figure needs to use the App framework rather than the `figure` framework

Comment: The new `uifigure`s are browser-based figures. [Maybe reading the corresponding articles on undocumentedmatlab might help.](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tag/uifigure)

Comment: @Will because what you've described is a big solution to a broad problem. If you provided the code for all of that, but you had a specific issue with the compiler, or perhaps with understanding a required class or syntax, then you've got a specific problem. Otherwise this is (albeit unintentionally) a broad question, because it falls into the "please write general purpose code for me from scratch" category. I'm not trying to be mean, just factual, happy to answer on a specific facet of this problem. Even well defined things can be broad, I'm not saying this is unclear.

Comment: @Wolfie I think you're confusing high-level with broad. There is no general purpose code to write from scratch to answer this question - just knowledge that the necessary software component exists and that using it will achieve the desired result.

Comment: @Will feel free to write the answer, if 4 more people don't agree with me the question won't be closed so this isn't worth discussion, cheers

Comment: @Will and everyone else, thanks for responding and trying to help out. all the resources from this will lead me in the correct path.

for wolfie, i do understand your point on being broad, but as will said, I was just wondering if such an idea was even possible, before wasting effort in something that cant be achieved